# Azure Pipeline- Copy files from one Repo to another Repo using YAML

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

There is a folder in one of the repositories (Source Repo) that I like to copy to another repository (Destination Repo) using **Azure Pipeline** (as they needed to be in sync)

so far I can Copy a folder in the same repository using:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\MyFolder\'
    Contents: |
      **
      !**\obj\**
      !**\bin\**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\DestFolder'
    flattenFolders: false
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
    preserveTimestamp: true
```

this is how I connect to another repository:

```
 resources:
   repositories:
   - repository: SourceRepo
     type: git
     name: MyCollection/SourceRepo
```

but I don't know how to get files from the source repo and place them in the Destination Repo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

after a lot of searching, this is the answer:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: SourceRepo
    type: git
    name: MyCollection/SourceRepo

steps:

- checkout: SourceRepo
  clean: true
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "restore DestRepo"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/DestRepo/**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "build DestRepo"
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/DestRepo/DestRepo/**/*.csproj'
    configuration: Release


# configurations for using git command
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(Agent.HomeDirectory)\externals\git\cmd
      git config --global user.email ""
      git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: checkout
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C RootRep checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: pull
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C DestRepo pull

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\SourceRepo\SourceFolder'
    Contents: |
      **
      !**\obj\**
      !**\bin\**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\DestRepo\DestFolder'
    flattenFolders: false
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
    # preserveTimestamp: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: add
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C DestRepo add --all

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: commit
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C DestRepo commit -m "Azure Pipeline Repository Integration"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C DestRepo push -u origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

Comment: the MS Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find some solution related to this problem, but instead of using a copy file task, I found a better way and we can use any number of repositories are resources in the build pipeline and we don't need to check out all these.

This is how my build pipeline looks like.

[image]

As you can see I have used two variables

1. $(System.AccessToken), this variable is available in Azure DevOps aka PAT(Personal Access Token)
2. $(Build.Repository.Uri) URL of the repository (this could be the URL of any repo in resources).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with almost the same issue, both repository can be found on my Azure DevOps tenant and I'm using ubuntu agent, here is my solution:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: main-repository
    type: git
    name: main
  - repository: secondary-repository
    type: git
    name: secondary

steps:
- checkout: self
#first checkout the main repository
#Build related tasks
# configurations for using git command and use the another repository
- checkout: secondary-repository
  persistCredentials: true
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Change directory
  inputs:
      script: |
        cd secondary-repository

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git config --global user.email "user@email.com"
      git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: pull
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository pull origin main
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/main-repository/folder/'
    Contents: '*.jar'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/secondary-repository/folder/'
    flattenFolders: false
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
    # preserveTimestamp: true


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: pull
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository checkout main

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: add
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository add --all

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: commit
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository commit -m "Azure Pipeline Repository Integration"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: status
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository status


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C secondary-repository push -u origin main
```

For this solution, you have to add permission for the "**Project Collection Build Service**" if there isn't. You can do it by going to the **repository settings** -> **Repositories** -> **Select the necessary repositories** -> Allow "**Contribute**" in each repository. [image]

After these steps you will be able to work on two different repositories in Azure.